# Eclipse+aptana in linux

Tags: eclipse

can we use eclipse+aptana plug-in in linux platform?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it seems so, have a look [here](http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Installing_Aptana_on_Linux). Have you tried running it and run into any specific issue?